# fmt.Println outputs are numbers instead of strings, how do I get the output to strings? Do I need to some conversion or is something wrong with code?

Tags: api, go, terraform, terraform-cloud

My goal is to get a list of workspaces in my terraform cloud account using the Go API Client. I've written some Go code, and whenever I run "go run main.go" in my terminal, the output shows numbers rather than the workspace names. Here is the go code...

```
package main

import (
"context"
"fmt"
"log"

    tfe "github.com/hashicorp/go-tfe"

)

func main() {

    config := &tfe.Config{
        Token: "my-token",
    }
    
    client, err := tfe.NewClient(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    // Create a Context
    ctx := context.Background()
    
    orgs, err := client.Organizations.List(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    
    }
    
    fmt.Println(orgs)
    
    space, err := client.Workspaces.List(ctx, "orgname", &tfe.WorkspaceListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(space, "test")

}
```

The output:

```
&{0xc0002ae090 \[0xc0002b0000\]}
&{0xc00000baa0 \[0xc000400000 0xc0004001e0 0xc0004003c0 0xc0004005a0 0xc000400780 0xc000400960 0xc000400b40 0xc000400d20 0xc000400f00 0xc0004010e0 0xc0004012c0 0xc0004014a0 0xc000401680 0xc000401860 0xc000401a40 0xc000401c20 0xc000401e00 0xc0004d8000 0xc0004d81e0 0xc0000001e0\]} test
```

I tried changing the "orgname" to a made up name, the output of the cli is:

```
&{0xc0000b6ff0 \[0xc0000da580\]}
2022/03/23 18:10:29 resource not found
exit status 1
```

This tells me that the "orgname" I have works and is actually grabbing workspaces within the organization. Just the output are numbers instead of names.

What I expect:

```
companyname
[develop__us-east-1__global, develop__us-east-1__compute]
```

Comment: Seems like you are printing the pointers. Try dereferencing them using '*', this should give you real values.

Comment: How would I do that? That sounds right as it mentions '*' in the documentation, I'm new to Go.

Answer (score 1):

When you're testing, it can be useful to use the formatting directives in Printf. For instance:

```go
fmt.Printf("orgs=%+v\n", orgs)
```

The `%+v` will guess at what orgs is and how a human might best understand its contents. For example, if it's a pointer, it will try to dereference the pointer and inspect it.

According to [the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/go-tfe#Organizations), the return value from `Organizations.List()` is `*OrganizationList`. That's a pointer to a type, so it can be `nil`. You'll want to check that before you dereference it later in your code.

It seems like OrganizationList is not guaranteed to return a complete result; it embeds a `*Pagination` pointer. But for our purposes, let's ignore that, as we can assume the object will return at least a few results.

OrganizationList also includes an `Items` member, which is `[]*Organization`. Reading this, that's a slice (you can think of this as a dynamically-sized array) of pointers to `Organization` objects. The canonical way to iterate through a slice in Go is `range`:

```go
for index := range orgs.Items {
  fmt.Printf("orgs[%d]: %+v\n", index, orgs.Items[index]);
}
```

But this is going to have a lot of stuff; an Organization object has a dozen or so fields. If all we want is the names, we do this:

```go
for index := range orgs.Items {
  if orgs.Items[index] != nil {
    fmt.Printf("orgs[%d].Name: %q\n", index, orgs[index].Name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Chris, you are amazing! Great explanation. I'm reading Learning Go by Oreilly and have come across some examples of slices and range, helped me understand what you're saying too. I tested this out tonight and it worked!

Comment: Looks like this only listed some of the workspaces, not all of them. Is there a limit? Or are most of them nil?

Comment: @sirdivine I'm not sure! Like I mentioned, your OrganizationList result includes a Pagination value, which I suspect is part of the Terraform API for returning more results if the current set is incomplete. I'd check that Pagination type documentation to see how to use it, which will likely have you making multiple calls to the API. At that point you should be able to get the complete result set.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the object is not a stringer.
You have some options:

1. Create a wrapper type that implement stringer interface `String() string` and implement your logic
2. Create a helper function thar perform this conversion on this particular type
3. Use spew.Dump / spew.Sdump qnd perhaps you can find some acceptable output. Check here: https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew
4. You can try to convert the object into a json (or other format) and print it. Perhaps it can be readable